# Show that derivate of $\varphi(v) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-av}} $ is $a\varphi(v)[1-\varphi(v)]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My steps:

$$
\frac{d\varphi(v)}{dv} = \frac{1'(1+e^{-av}) - 1(1+e^{-av})}{(1+e^{-av})^{2}} = \frac{ae^{-av}}{(1+e^{-av})^{2}} = ae^{-av}\frac{1}{1+e^{-av}}\frac{1}{1+e^{-av}} \Leftrightarrow a\varphi(v)[e^{-ax}\varphi(v)]
$$

> How do I get to the final expression? Or where did I wrong to get stuck in that?

Comment: $$\frac{e^{-av}}{1+e^{-av}}=1-\varphi(v)$$

Comment: @PeterForeman sorry I didn't understand, but why is this equivalent?

Comment: $$1-\varphi(v)=\frac{1+e^{-av}}{1+e^{-av}}-\frac{1}{1+e^{-av}}=\frac{e^{-av}}{1+e^{-av}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{e^{-av}}{1+e^{-av}}=1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-av}}$$